# Find duplicate in array of BitArray

Tags: c#, duplicates, bitarray

I have array of Bitarray (each element consists of 128 bits) and I want to find duplicate of elements of it.
I tried this code:

```
     Bitarray [] bitsarr=//something;
     string g=//convert the array of bitarray to binary string
      int numOfBytes = g.Length / 8;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
      {
          bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(g.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2);
      }
      int[] bytesAsInts = bytes.Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
      var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
      foreach (var num in bytesAsInts)
      {
          if (!dict.ContainsKey(num))
          {
              dict.Add(num, 0);
          }
          dict[num]++;
      }

      foreach (var kvp in dict)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} repeats {1} times", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
      }
```

but I don't want to convert it to int because the results will be false.
I want to know the duplication of each element of array of bitarray.
Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried group by linq query?

Comment: No, please tell me more about it and how can I use it?

Comment: something like this var groups = bytes.GroupBy(b => b);
            foreach (var group in groups)
                Console.WriteLine("Value {0} has {1} items", group.Key, group.Count());

Comment: but  I want to find duplicates of bitarray elements in an array (not bytes array)

Comment: Once you find the duplicate just reverse the operation convert your byte back to bitarray that way you will get the original bitarray which is being repeated(duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `BitArray.Xor(BitArray)` to find duplicates, on MSDN:

> The bitwise exclusive OR operation returns true if exactly one operand is true, and returns false if both operands have the same Boolean value

After XOR operation you can check is all bits in BitArray are False:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsAllFalse(this BitArray bitArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bitArray[i] == true)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

P.S. Mind that `BitArray.Xor(BitArray)` modifying current object, save values in BitArray object before calling it.

Comment: Can you please explain more ?